# Getting uninitialized constant Twilio::REST::RequestError

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I keep getting the same error since I upgraded to:

```
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 5.0.0.rc4'
```

**The call was successful set to Twilio**, but the **getting some error**.

```
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:59:in `rescue in call'

require "rubygems"
require "twilio-ruby"

def call
  @twilio = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token

  begin
    @call = @twilio.account.calls.create({
     :to => , 
      :from => twilio_number,
      :url => url,
      :method => "GET",
      :if_machine => "Hangup",
      :timeout => "20"
    })

    # Getting current call status (seems like error here...!)
    get_status(@call.sid)

  rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => error
    @err_msg = error.message
    puts @err_msg
    #returned error is like below:
    #NameError (uninitialized constant Twilio::REST::RequestError)
  end
end
```

**Code for getting current call status:**

```
def get_status(sid)
  @twilio = Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid, auth_token
  @call = @twilio.account.calls.get(sid)
  puts "Process Status : " + @call.status
  return @call.status
end
```

Please help to figure it out.

Thank you!

Comment: I TRIED TO USE DIFFERENT VERSION

 **gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.4.0'**
and I didn't received the same error as using the **version 5.0.0**.

Comment: so did that work or are you getting a different error now?

Comment: Hi @kulkarniankita, it works in version 4.4.0, but not in 5.0.0

Comment: Hi @kulkarniankita, that line is for the catching of error using begin....
 rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => error

Comment: Can you try `::Twilio::REST::Client.new account_sid..` instead of `Twilio::REST.....`

Answer (score 2):

For version 5, Try `Twilio::REST::RestError`.

This is documented [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby/migration-guide#error-handling):

> There are new classes to rescue errors from. The new library now uses the Twilio::REST::RestError class.